# Read XML file Attributes and Elements using C#

Tags: c#, xml

My XML file looks like:

```
<device name="dev. 1" nodes="16" scenarios="20">
  <package>Pack. 1</package>
  <info>info...</info>
  <picture>pic</picture>
  <nodes>
    <node no="1" name="OUT_1" type="source"/>
    <node no="2" name="OUT_2" type="source"/>
    <node no="3" name="OUT_3" type="source"/>
    <node no="4" name="OUT_4" type="source"/>
  </nodes>
  <scenario name="scenario 1">
    <zth m_node="1" d_node="1" model="table" points="190">
      <data time="1" value="0.1"/>
      <data time="2" value="2"/>
      <data time="2" value="4"/>
    </zth>
    <zth m_node="1" d_node="2" model="table" points="190">
      <data time="1" value="0.3"/>
      <data time="2" value="4"/>
    </zth>
  </scenario>
  <scenario name="scenario 2">
    <zth m_node="1" d_node="1" model="table" points="190">
      <data time="2" value="2"/>
      <data time="1" value="0.3"/>
      <data time="2" value="4"/>
    </zth>
    <zth m_node="1" d_node="2" model="table" points="190">
      <data time="1" value="0.3"/>
      <data time="2" value="4"/>
    </zth>
  </scenario>
</device>
```

The data I need to read is:
The Attribute name from the Element scen from the is in the `<data>`, I need to get the time and value from the data into arrays but only when the `d_node="2"` in the `<zth>`.

This is what I have tried:

```
    public class Scenario {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<string> ZthList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Zth {
        public string m_node { get; set; }
        public string d_node { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
    public class XMLReader
    {

        public void xmlReader()
        {

            string currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            //getting the directory
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(
            Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(currentDir, @"..\..\" + @"utils\XML\XMLFile1.xml")));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(currentDir, @"..\..\" + @"utils\XML\XMLFile1.xml"));
            var scenarios = (from s in doc.Root.Elements("scenario")
                             select new Scenario{
                                 name = (string)s.Attribute("name"), 
                                 ZthList = s.Elements("zth")
                                            .Select(r => new Zth
                                            {
                                                m_node = (string)r.Attribute("m_node"),
                                                d_node = (string)r.Attribute("d_node"),
                                                time = (string)r.Element("data").Attribute("time"),
                                                value = (string)r.Element("data").Attribute("value"),
                                            }).ToList()
                             }).ToList();
            var zth_d_node = scenarios.Where(x => x.ZthList.Any(r => r.d_node == "1")).ToList();
            var s_names = scenarios.Where(x => x.Element("").Value.Equals("name")).toList();

            Console.WriteLine("List: ");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", scenarios));
        }
    }
```

I am getting and error: `Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<project1.utils.Zth>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`

Also the data from the `time` and `value` is of type double I changed it to string because I was getting a similar error but still it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to improve your model to the structure of xml data. See:

```
public class Scenario {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Zth> ZthList { get; set; }
}

public class Zth {
    public string m_node { get; set; }
    public string d_node { get; set; }
    public List<Data> data { get; set; }
}

public class Data {
    public string t { get; set; }
    public string v { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(...);
List<Scenario> scenarios = xdoc.Descendants("scenario")
    .Select(x=> new Scenario()
        {
            name= x.Attribute("name").Value, 
            ZthList= x.Descendants("zth")
                .Select(y=> new Zth()
                {
                    m_node = y.Attribute("m_node").Value,
                    d_node = y.Attribute("d_node").Value, 
                    data = y.Descendants("data")
                        .Select(z => new Data()
                        {
                            t =  z.Attribute("time").Value,
enter code here

                            v = z.Attribute("value").Value,
                        })
                        .ToList()
                }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

If you would like to get only those `zth` nodes where `d_node` is equal to `1`, you can change this line:

```
...
ZthList= x.Descendants("zth")
    .Where(n=> n.Attribute("d_node").Value == "1")  //condition was added
    .Select(y=> new Zth()
...
```

Then result will look like:

[image: List of scenarios]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was trying to create a list with all the `time` values but only when the `d_node` attribute is 1 in the `zth` element, how can I save this in another list?

Comment: @kristian, what if the `d_node` attribute is not equal to `1`? `data` member of `zth` class will be `null`! Is it ok?

Comment: If `d_node` is not 1 the time and value can be ignored, it is relevant only when it's 1.

Comment: When I display the values of the `t`: `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", scenarios.Select(x => x.ZthList.Select(y => y.data.Select(z => z.t)))));` I don't get the values, but I get this instead: `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator 2[prj.utils.Zth,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[System.String]], System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator 2[prj.utils.Zth,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[System.String]]` . I tried to get the names of scenarios this way and it works: `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", scenarios.Select(x => x.name)));` Did I get something wrong?

Comment: `foreach(Scenario sc in scenarios)
 {
  Console.WriteLine($"---=== {sc.name} ===---");
  foreach(Zth z in sc.ZthList)
  {
   Console.WriteLine("times: {0}", string.Join(";", z.data.Select(x=>x.t)));
   Console.WriteLine("values: {0}", string.Join(";", z.data.Select(x=>x.v)));
  }
 }`

Answer (score 1):

I made a bunch of changes. I always recommend to avoid "var" unless it is necessary.  You were totally confused because you didn't know the variable types. :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XMLReader xReader = new XMLReader();
            xReader.xmlReader(FILENAME);
        }
 
    }
    public class Scenario
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Zth> ZthList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Zth
    {
        public string m_node { get; set; }
        public string d_node { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
    public class XMLReader
    {

        public void xmlReader(string filename)
        {


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            List<Scenario> scenarios = (from s in doc.Root.Elements("scenario")
                             select new Scenario
                             {
                                 name = (string)s.Attribute("name"),
                                 ZthList = s.Elements("zth")
                                            .Select(r => new Zth()
                                            {
                                                m_node = (string)r.Attribute("m_node"),
                                                d_node = (string)r.Attribute("d_node"),
                                                time = (string)r.Element("data").Attribute("time"),
                                                value = (string)r.Element("data").Attribute("value")
                                            }).ToList()
                             }).ToList();
            List<Scenario> zth_d_node = scenarios.Where(x => x.ZthList.Any(r => r.d_node == "1")).ToList();
            List<Scenario> s_names = scenarios.Where(x => x.name == "name").ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("List: ");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", scenarios.Select(x => x.name )));
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: In this line `List<Scenario> zth_d_node = scenarios.Where(x => x.ZthList.Any(r => r.d_node == "1")).ToList();` I was trying to create another list where I "filter" through the `zth` elements and check if `d_node` is one, if this is the case I want to save the `time` values of the element `data`. How can I save these values in a list, the code that I tried just displays only "true" values, but not the actual data.

Comment: You are seeing the results of the WHERE (which is either true or false).  You need a SELECT after the WHERE to return data.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific. How can I select the `time` attribute from data in this case?

Comment: It is already these.  I added a picture to my answer so you can see.